# New coordinates in terms of old from Jacobian-- Software?

Tags: differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, software, computational-physics

Fellow geometry enthusiasts:

I am studying a particular geometry and I would like to change from one set of coordinates to a new set that makes the metric unimodular (i.e. it's determinant is one). The components of the metric are rather complicated functions of the coordinates, so I don't know how to solve the system of linear first order PDEs that I get from the Jacobian. Is anyone aware of any software that can give me the new coordinates in terms of the old ones given the Jacobian of the transformation? I have Maple 18, but I have not been able to find this capability in Maple.

Comment: Software requests are typically off-topic. Also, in my opinion, it is absolutely essential that you understand *what* is being computed (i.e., know how to solve a PDE), even if you are letting a computer do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the "help"... I know what I'm computing-- it's a new coordinate system. I just can't solve *this* PDE by hand as it involves rational functions of sixteenth order polynomials. In any case it turns out that pdsolve for maple has been recently improved to handle systems, so that is a possible answer for those browsing this post with similar problems.

Comment: You said, "I don't know how to solve the system of linear first order PDEs" that *strongly* suggests that you don't know what it is you're doing & are looking for shortcuts.

Comment: Maple is Turing complete, which means that it can compute everything that can be computed within the limitations of the computer (and this is certainly well inside those)... which makes it the more important to listen to Kyle: computers are useless, if you don't know how to solve the problem (at least in theory) yourself. All they can do is to solve it faster for you. Look at it this way: this is a great opportunity to learn about 1st order PDEs AND about Maple programming.

Comment: @KyleKanos: He said "The components of the metric are rather complicated functions of the coordinates..." Your choice to interpret the rest of that sentence as evidence that OP doesn't know what he's doing and is looking for short cuts seems arbitrary and disparaging to me. That said, OP should give more detail: what are these complex functions? What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Curious, this is admittedly more a question about Maple programming (which I am new to) than about physics or PDEs per se. The particular geometry I am working with is the so-called delta=2 Tomimatso-Sato spacetime. The solution has naked singularities and I am interested in transforming to coordinates that make the spatial sector regular-- that is the ADM metric and momentum have no singularities-- so I want a spatially unimodular gauge. I cannot integrate this system by hand, so I am hoping maple can at least give me the ranges of the new coordinates.